# How do I edit the innerHTML of an index page from an iframe using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, innerhtml, getelementbyid

On my index page amongst several different divs is a single iframe with id = 'myframe', that iframe has a src = order.html and that page has a bunch of different radio buttons and checkboxes with values associated with them.

I've currently run into a wall writing the javascript function to edit a div (with id = 'purchase') on the index page of this website to display current orders/purchases.

```
function addAlbum(boxElement){


            var iframe = document.getElementById('myframe');

            var s = iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementById('purchase').innerHTML;

            i = boxElement.value.indexOf("|");
            clean_string = boxElement.value.substring(0,i);
            //price = parseInt(boxElement.value.substring(i +1, boxElement.value.length));
            replaceString = "";

            if(boxElement.checked){

                s += '<div class="one_record">';
                s += clean_string;
                s += '</div>';
            }
            else{
                replaceString = '<div class="one_record">';
                replaceString += clean_string;
                replaceString += '</div>';

                s.replace(replaceString, "");

            }

        }
```

When I run my function I get an error saying: "Cannot read property 'contentWindow' of null" meaning that it cant find my iframe (id = 'myframe'). Any advice is most appreciated.

Comment: I'm thinking the problem could be that the iFrame is a "window" object already, so you might consider changing contentWindow to contentDocument and see if that resolves your issue.
You could try accessing the document object of your iFrame with something like:
var iframe = window.frames["myframe"];
var s = iframe.document.getElementById('purchase').innerHTML;

Comment: I revamped my answer earlier, I think I actually found the error you are having.

Answer (score 0):

<s>In the past I've found that you can not edit the contents of an iframe when you capture it through the ID with `document.getElementById()` you need to go through the `window.frames` i.e. `window.frames.iFrameName.document.body.innerHTML`.</s>

You should be able to access the IFrame's document like this (with you more or less are):

```
var frame = document.getElementById('frame');
frame.onload = function() {
    var frameDoc = frame.contentDocument ? frame.contentDocument : frame.contentWindow.document;
    frameDoc.body.innerHTML += '<br />Appended from the parent Page';
}
```

After correcting my own ignorance  on the issue I took a closer look at what's going own with your code nothing really stood out. In fact at first I had problems replicating the issue cause your code actually worked for me. Usually this means that the iFrame has not loaded.

So I tried that and the only errors I was getting were that the innerHTML of the iFrame's element `getElementById('purchase')` was NULL, not the `contentWindow`.

And then it hit me, you are calling the function `addAlbum(boxElement)` before the iframe exists in the DOM. With this HTML I got the exact same error in IE:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    var frame = document.getElementById('frame');
    (function() {
        var s = frame.contentWindow.document.getElementById('s1').innerHTML;
            s += '<br />Appended from the parent Page';
    })();

    </script>
    <iframe id="frame" src="internal.htm"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Note how both the script and the iframe are in the body and the iframe is bellow the script. I am willing to bet you have an analog situation, because nothing else caused such a distinct error. Unfortunately I can't pinpoint your error without seeing your HTML.